# Nested Mongodb Query needing multi seareshes

Tags: mongodb

Hi I'm new with mongodb and I have to write a query to check if each field in database has a parent, if yes change the hasChild field to "true" else leave it be the default value of false.
Here is sample of one Document.

```
    {
      "_id":"5e19ef611052250ba51abb7b",
      "name":"shampoo",
      "price":12.99,
      "hasChild":true
    }

   {
     "_id":"5e1b268d25fe046b3518dcb9",
     "name":"conditioner",
     "price":"13.99",
     "parent":"5e19ef611052250ba51abb7b",
     "hasChild":false
   }
```

I though a query which could ,while updating a filed search in other documents, check whether they have a parent id same as current documents id and set true/false would work out. but I couldn't find a way to write it. I would appreciate any ideas. 
note that "_id" and "parent" are ObjectId.

Comment: Please share collection at jsoneditor online ?

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a8a89569305c4371a3a9941524f8450a here you can see it

Comment: Please share whole collection data at jsoneditor online

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with aggregation framework.

Something like this with [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) and [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/):

```
db.getCollection("yourcollection").aggregate(


    [

        {
            $addFields: {
                "hasChild": {
                     $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$parent", undefined ] }, then: false, else: true }
                }
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

Comment: This is very genius but in result only child documents' "hasChild' turned "true". any ideas on that?

Comment: one other problem is that is the child document also has a child, this aggregation could not find that.

Comment: Can you show me an output sample of your collection that you hope to retrieve?